# what does "Aggregate Translation Items" mean?

Tags: 2011, translation-manager

When you open a Schema, there is a check box named "Aggregate Translation Items"? Can anybody explain what it means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aggregation adds all the Content Manager items included in a Translation Job into a single item on the translation management system instead of in separate files for each item.

Read more here [Aggregating Content Manager items in a Translation Job](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?c=t&action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DAggregate%2520Translation%2520Items&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1409951234615&currentQuery=Aggregate%2520Translation%2520Items&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-B4678920-21BE-486A-9C11-91F82A44E737&query=Aggregate%2520Translation%2520Items&scope=&filename=GUID-B4678920-21BE-486A-9C11-91F82A44E737.xml&docid=GUID-B4678920-21BE-486A-9C11-91F82A44E737&inner_id=&tid=79cd0f06-f9ae-475d-a81a-00432b303a4e&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false) [Login required]